# overriding declarations in extensions is not supported - swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I made a minimal reproducible code of my issue.

```
enum Animal {
    case cat
    case dog
}

protocol AdoptPet {
    func petIs(pet: Animal)
}
class Delegate {
   
}
extension Delegate: AdoptPet {
    func petIs(pet: Animal) {
        print("not implemeted")
    }
}

class Girl: Delegate {
}

extension Girl {
    override func petIs(pet: Animal) { // overriding declarations in extensions is not supported
        print(pet)
    }
}

class PetCenter {
    init () {
       
    }
    func setup(adpoter: Delegate){
        let pet: Animal = .cat
        adpoter.petIs(pet: pet)
    }
}
let petCenter = PetCenter()
let adpoter: Girl = Girl()
petCenter.setup(adpoter: adpoter)
```

What should I change in the code to make this compile ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding non-@objc declarations from extensions is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364212/overriding-non-objc-declarations-from-extensions-is-not-supported)

Comment: Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564557/declarations-from-extensions-cannot-be-overridden-yet-in-swift-4?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move both the declaration of the function and the override into the type declarations from extensions. So `Delegate` needs to contain the `petIs` implementation in its declaration and `Girl` needs to override the `petIs` function in its body as well (using the `override` keyword) rather than in an extension.

```
class Delegate: AdoptPet {
   func petIs(pet: Animal) {
        print("not implemeted")
    }
}

class Girl: Delegate {
    override func petIs(pet: Animal) {
        print(pet)
    }
}

class PetCenter {
    init () {
       
    }
    func setup(adopter: Delegate){
        let pet: Animal = .cat
        adopter.petIs(pet: pet)
    }
}

let petCenter = PetCenter()
let adopter = Girl()
petCenter.setup(adopter: adopter) // cat
```